# Fixing line breaks in methods with Resharper?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, resharper, jetbrains-ide

I have this method that I don't really know what to do with. I know resharper offers some sort of functionality to format it better, obviously the first if statement should be an extra line break away from the first line WriteString method, and inside the else the first else should be an extra line break away from `WriteInteger(item.Data.SpriteId);`

Hopefully you can get what I'm trying to do just from that short explanation... If I run a code clean up on Resharper I know it doesn't do this from past experiences, does anyone know how I can configure this?

An example, this code below...

```
public void DoSomething() {
    WriteString(item.Data.Type.ToString());
    if (item.Data.Type.ToString().ToLower() == "b")
    {
        WriteString(item.Data.ItemName);
    }
    else
    {
        WriteInteger(item.Data.SpriteId);
        if (item.Data.InteractionType == InteractionType.WALLPAPER || item.Data.InteractionType == InteractionType.FLOOR || item.Data.InteractionType == InteractionType.LANDSCAPE)
        {
            WriteString(item.Name.Split('_')[2]);
        }
        else if (item.Data.InteractionType == InteractionType.BOT) //Bots
        {
            WriteString(!PlusEnvironment.GetGame().GetCatalog().TryGetBot(item.ItemId, out var catalogBot) ? "hd-180-7.ea-1406-62.ch-210-1321.hr-831-49.ca-1813-62.sh-295-1321.lg-285-92" : catalogBot.Figure);
        }
        else if (item.ExtraData != null)
        {
            WriteString(item.ExtraData ?? string.Empty);
        }
        WriteInteger(item.Amount);
        WriteBoolean(item.IsLimited);
        if (item.IsLimited)
        {
            WriteInteger(item.LimitedEditionStack);
            WriteInteger(item.LimitedEditionStack - item.LimitedEditionSells);
        }
    }
}
```

Would become something like this...

```
public void DoSomething() {
    WriteString(item.Data.Type.ToString());

    if (item.Data.Type.ToString().ToLower() == "b")
    {
        WriteString(item.Data.ItemName);
    }
    else
    {
        WriteInteger(item.Data.SpriteId);

        if (item.Data.InteractionType == InteractionType.WALLPAPER || item.Data.InteractionType == InteractionType.FLOOR || item.Data.InteractionType == InteractionType.LANDSCAPE)
        {
            WriteString(item.Name.Split('_')[2]);
        }
        else if (item.Data.InteractionType == InteractionType.BOT) //Bots
        {
            WriteString(!PlusEnvironment.GetGame().GetCatalog().TryGetBot(item.ItemId, out var catalogBot) ? "hd-180-7.ea-1406-62.ch-210-1321.hr-831-49.ca-1813-62.sh-295-1321.lg-285-92" : catalogBot.Figure);
        }
        else if (item.ExtraData != null)
        {
            WriteString(item.ExtraData ?? string.Empty);
        }

        WriteInteger(item.Amount);
        WriteBoolean(item.IsLimited);

        if (item.IsLimited)
        {
            WriteInteger(item.LimitedEditionStack);
            WriteInteger(item.LimitedEditionStack - item.LimitedEditionSells);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_formatting.html

Comment: Formatting of Code in C# is not part of the language - I for me would never put an opening curly bracket on the same line as the function it belongs to  - but thats personal preference (or follows team coding guidelines). vs2017 comes with some configurable codeformatting and Strg+KC formats the code accordingly. Resharper also has settings to rule how it formats the code. Set it up and use it. How? See https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/NETCOM/ReSharper+Customization+Guide#ReSharperCustomizationGuide-FormattingStyles

Comment: I realize resharpper has a code formatting section, the question was how to setup this specific thing, I can't find it anywhere?

Comment: It is described at 
 https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/NETCOM/ReSharper+Customization+Guide#ReSharperCustomizationGuide-Language-specificFormattingStyles "BlankLineSettings"

Comment: That really doesn't help, I've tried changing a few of them settings but they either don't do anything, or do too much. I'm specifically asking someone to tell me step by step what settings to change.

Answer (score 1):

Cited from https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/NETCOM/ReSharper+Customization+Guide#ReSharperCustomizationGuide-Language-specificFormattingStyles

> go to **Code Editing | [Language] | Formatting Style**. Depending on the
>   language there may be up to hundred different settings, which allow
>   you to define every detail of your code layout. Formatting settings
>   may be divided into several pages:
>
> **Braces Layout** lists settings that determine how curly braces are laid
>   out. This feature is only available for languages that use curly
>   braces for scoping, such as C#. **Blank Lines** lists settings that
>   determine how many blank lines are added in particular use instances.
>   A value of 0 implies that no blank lines are used.

You look for the **Blank Lines** settings. Your "use" is probably blank lines before/after (conditional) blocks.

Comment: Theres no setting for before/after if statements (conditional blocks) unfortunately. That was the first thing I checked.

Comment: @t2035816 `"Blank lines in Code"`/`" Before statements with child blocks"` set to 1 - maybe also 1 for `"Before statements with control transfer"` ... in Options,CodeEditing,C#,FormattingStyle,BlankLines

Comment: Resharper 2017.3.1

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want...

[image]

Comment: This isn't showing up on my RS, I even tried searching it via the search. I'm using version 2017.2.2.

Comment: @t2035816 I'm on Resharper 2017.3.

Comment: Might be the "Before statements with child blocks" as well - no idea whats the diff - the latter probably with a subscope by `{ .... }`